# Including a dynamic/moving background in Bootstrap website

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make an animated background (javascript/css) as my site's body background (or the equivalent)? I can fit it in a div and make it work, but cannot figure out setting it as the background. Note: I'm using bootstrap.

I'm assuming I just select the body in my javascript, but I might have been doing it wrong. Something like: `canvas = document.body` and then remove the 'myHolder' since the holder would then be the body.

Below is my **HTML** div to display the content. (I know this is wrong for setting it as background, but its the only way I can get it to display)

```
<div id="myHolder">
<canvas id="myAnimation"></canvas>
</div>
```

Below is my **javascript** (the parts related to the canvas/div above):

```
initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('myHolder');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('myAnimation');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** My page now contains the following code:
The animation is displaying as the background, but the other divs are pushed further down the page still. However, the background is displayed correctly behind the other divs.

```
    <style>
    #myAnimation {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="myHolder">
    <canvas id="myAnimation" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
    </div>
....page content...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, this is just a CSS change!

```
#myAnimation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -100; //Put your background behind the rest of your content
}
```

note that this will stretch your canvas, so you'll need to set width and height to 100% as attributes if you want to avoid that.

```
<canvas id="myAnimation" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comment: You may need "html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}" to get the positioning to work correctly (full screen).

Comment: Thanks, Looks like I'm half-way there now. I updated my post with the issue. I can provide a link to my site for clarity, if that is appropriate. I'm not a pro at this stuff.

Comment: @heyitsmyusername There's no need to wrap your canvas in `<div id="myHolder">`. Try removing that and see if it helps. If not a website link would help us help you. :)

Comment: When I remove that, the animated background does not show. (note: I havent modified the js at all)

Comment: Don't laugh at my project ;) I'm learning as I go: http://helpbot.org/ (only concerned about homepage) Note: on a large display, the content would/should nomally all fit without scrolling.

Comment: @heyitsmyusername Don't remove the canvas element, just remove the `<div id="myHolder">` that surrounds it. That fixes it for me. Website is looking good, by the way. :)

Comment: @J4G I did that as before. And just the normal background shows. Look at it again. Sorry if I'm confused. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I'm assume you're using #myHolder for something else - maybe to get your canvas element in the first place? Try setting it's height to 0, then. `#myHolder { height: 0; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94654/discussion-between-heyitsmyusername-and-j4g).

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. (browser just had to be reset)